# Lawvere - Conceptual Mathematics - Criterion for Determination of Maps

Tags: functions, proof-verification

This is a problem from Lawvere's Conceptual Mathematics, in a section talking about determination problems and retraction maps.

Suppose two maps of sets $f: A \to B$, $h: A \to C$ satisfy the condition: If $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$, then $ h(a_1) = h(a_2)$. Must there be a map $g: B \to C$ with $h = g \circ f$?

I think the answer is yes, because $g$ should essentially be determined by $h$. We know for any $a \in A$ there is an element $b \in B$ such that $f(a) = b$, and we know there is an element $c \in C$ with $h(a) = c$, so I think we should just define $g(b) = c$. Such a $g$ is well defined because, by our assumption, if we have $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ then $h(a_1) = (g \circ f)(a_1) = (g \circ f)(a_2) = h(a_2)$.

That proof seems hand-wavy, and too easy. Is there a better way to put the argument (assuming it is true)?

Comment: WHere did you use the hypothesis that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)\implies h(a_1)=h(a_2)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I think we need that assumption to make sure our $g$ is well defined, otherwise it is possible that we have $f(a_1) = b_1 = f(a_2)$ but $h(a_1) = c_1 \ne c_2 = h(a_2)$, which means an ill-defined g

Comment: Besides what @JoséCarlosSantos has already pointed out, there's another issue here. Let $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$, and $C=\{4,5\}$. Define $f:A\to B$ by $f(1)=2$. Define $h:A\to C$ by $h(1)=4$. Try applying your construction to this example. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @zipirovich do you mean that $g(3)$ is undefined? I suppose it doesn't really matter where we map $g(3)$ to (since it isn't in the image of $f$) as long as we map it to something, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. And yes, it doesn't really matter as long we map it into something, anything at all. But you HAVE TO map into something. By not mentioning it at all, you left it undefined, so you effectively didn't define the desired map $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exactly the right idea. And we've already resolved the issue of defining the desired map $g$ for all elements of $B$ in the comments thread above. But you still don't have a valid proof of why $g$ is well-defined — as I said, you understand the key idea for it, but it's not expressed properly. The

> Such a $g$ is well defined because, by our assumption, if we have $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ then $h(a_1)=(g\circ f)(a_1)=(g\circ f)(a_2)=h(a_2)$

part doesn't even seem to address the question of $g$ being well-defined.

Let's review carefully: how did you define $g$? First of all, I presume we are given that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are non-empty sets. Then you need to define $g(b)$ for any $b\in B$. There are two cases:

- if $b$ is in the image of $f$, then $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in A$, and we define $g(b)=h(a)$ (which is exactly what you said in your original post, but without using one more named variable $c$);
- if $b$ is not in the image of $f$, then … (what we discussed in the comments).

Where can we have any troubles with $g$ being or not well-defined? Only in the first case, because defining $g(b)$ depends on the choice of a certain $a\in A$. We must show that in fact the result is independent of this choice. So we need to examine it more carefully.

Assume $b$ is in the image of $f$. What if we have that $b=f(a_1)$ and $b=f(a_2)$ for  two distinct $a_1,a_2\in A$, $a_1\ne a_2$? By assumption, since $b=f(a_1)=f(a_2)$, we know that $h(a_1)=h(a_2)$. So defining $g(b)=h(a_1)$ or $g(b)=h(a_2)$ yields the same result. This is a proof that the definition of $g$ is independent of choices made.

Comment: great, thank you, that's very clear!